# Mocha beforeEach not running

Tags: mocha.js

I have seen lots of questions about this but all of the fixes simply does not work with my code.

What am I doing wrong? My beforeEach doesnt get executed.

This is the unit test code:

```
var assert = require('assert');

var environmentConfiguration;
var fs = require('fs');
var expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('environmentConfiguration', function() {

    beforeEach('some description', function() {
        console.log("hello")
      });
    describe('#configFile null configFile', function() {

        var result = environmentConfiguration.load(null)
        var expectedConfiguration = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./ISPRemotingService.config.json'));

        it('should return current ISP environment configuration', function() {
            assert(result, expectedConfiguration);
        });
    });

});
```

I have also applied simpler versions from Mocha's documentation and beforeEach doesn't gets executed.

Comment: Did you try putting your beforeEach inside of the inner describe block?

Answer (score 0):

Another exception was blocking the unit tests to even reach there. My bad